# Micronaut @Requires default declaration

Tags: java, annotations, micronaut

Are `@Requires("environment")` and `@Requires(env = "environment")` equivalent?

In case they're not, which is the behavior of the default declaration of [@Requires](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Requires.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default (no name specified) argument of an annotation is always the parameter named `value`. So no, they are not equivalent. These are:

```
@Requires("environment")
@Requires(value = "environment")
```